# How do I plot y value - 1 in R. I have differenced the x values and as such lengths no longer match causing issues with the plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's the code Im using in R.

```
plot3<-qplot(y = ('year' -1 ), diff(infl), geom = 'path', xlab='Year', ylab='% change Inflation', main='Year on Year difference in inflation rate')
plot4<-qplot(y= ('year' - 1), diff(unem), geom = 'path', xlab='Year', ylab='% change in Unemployment', main= 'Year on Year difference in unemployment rate', col='blue')
```

Comment: Don't put quotes around `year`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.